# How to do customization in the existing swagger-ui.html file

Tags: html, spring-boot, web-applications, swagger-ui, springfox

I just want to build a UI page (HTML) where I just need to invoke my REST GET, and PUT methods and display the response back.

I already implemented swagger-ui.html in my code and I can do the above activity in the swagger-ui.html file.

[image]

I just used the below two dependencies in the pom.xml file to consume the swagger API.

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
     <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
     <version>2.6.1</version>
   </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

I'm not able to see any css or html file to override in the project since it's downloaded as jar file and added into maven dependencies as like below:

[image]

**Is there any way to override the default css and html skelton using java code?**  if yes how can we do that. Is there any blog or resource will help me to do that ? I can able to see only swagger.properties file in src/main/resources and this file had nothing.

I just want to change the default format of the swagger-ui.html file like I just want to add text box and submit button and changing the logo and bg color.

I'm not sure how can I achieve this . Can someone lead me to achieve this